# PHP file upload (3.5 MB) upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I trying to use file input to upload a 3.5MB file, but when I try to upload it, I get a $_FILES['error'] == 2, I believe that is telling me that the file is way too big.

what can I do to get this to upload?

here is some of my code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
<input type="file" id="home_pdf" name="home_pdf">
```

my php settings are the following:

```
post_max_size = 128M
memory_limit = 128M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_execution_time = 30
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Comment: 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ???

Comment: You might want to change the form's MAX_FILE_SIZE to something more reasonable, like 134217728 (128M).

Comment: `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = OVERKILL;`

Comment: Also get it working with a much smaller file first, to confirm that size is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting a realistic value of "MAX_FILE_SIZE" in your form. Say, 4194304 = 4MB

Comment: I just tested the issue and confirmed the large number causes overflows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is too big of a number, and overflows. Try 134217728 instead (128MB).

PHP has a maximum int value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 on 64 bit installations and 2,147,483,647 on 32-bit installations.

**I've tested this and can reproduce your issue and it gets fixed by lowering the value.**

See [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that it was too large and the transfer failed. Keep in mind: fooling this setting on the browser side is quite easy, so never rely on files with a greater size being blocked by this feature. It is merely a convenience feature for users on the client side of the application. The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however, cannot be fooled.

Answer (score 2):

Your MAX_FILE_SIZE field is too big.

[from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
>
> Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form

Answer (score 1):

According to docs:

> *UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE*
>
> Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the *MAX_FILE_SIZE* directive that was specified in the HTML form.

You should check the *MAX_FILE_SIZE* directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Also, as noted from @BrandonWamboldt, you have specified an invalid attribute value for the *MAX_FILE_SIZE* directive.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly, but sometimes it is necessary in upload script to add a setting for php_ini. Example:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 120);
ini_set("max_input_time", 120);
ini_set("memory_limit", "128M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "10M");
ini_set("post_max_size", "10M");
```

For some reason this works. I had a similar problem and that was my solution.
My opinion for name MAX_FILE_SIZE and value 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is realy bad move and not recommended to be visible. That part define in PHP upload function and reduce the number of zeros (the value is tooooooooo large).